# Put validation on user input in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to put a validation when user enter the value he should enter
only numeric value but the user will enter the values in below format

```
Echo Build Number in the Format 5.1.2.44
set /p Build="enter Build Number Please : "
```

If he puts the values in 5.1.2.3 then he needs to identify that it is
numeric..he can use any character `?/.,` between the values instead of
`.`(dot)

Valid examples are `5.1.2.3`

Invalid examples are `5.2.A.3`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to verify that each value between the delimiters is a number.

```
@echo off
set "xResult=valid"
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=?/.," %%A in ("%Build%") do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=1234567890" %%n in ("%%A") do set "xResult=invalid"
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=1234567890" %%n in ("%%B") do set "xResult=invalid"
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=1234567890" %%n in ("%%C") do set "xResult=invalid"
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=1234567890" %%n in ("%%D") do set "xResult=invalid"
)
echo %xResult%
```

This works by first parsing the Build string into four separate values (`A-D`) by the delimiters (`?/.,`) and checking if each of those values are only comprised of the numbers (`0-9`).